# Can NSIS's $TEMP value be over-ridden?

Tags: nsis

I have a customer using Host Intrusion Protection and has set every User's temp folder not to allow execution (C:\users\\AppData\Local\Temp). NSIS extracts all plugin dlls and its own dlls into a folder below %TEMP%. The problem is nothing is allow to execute from temp so the entire install fails. What I need to know is how to tell NSIS to use a different folder. The only work around I can find is to edit the TEMP and TMP values under the registry key HCU\Environment from "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp" to something like C:\NSISTEMP. However even though this works changing the registry and then putting it back is not really an option. I also cannot just redirect InitPluginDir as that only effects plug-ins and not the rest of what NSIS extracts (icons xml files etc...). Any ideas?s

Comment: Why wouldn't InitPluginDir work?  If the issue is with "nothing is allow to execute from temp" then you can still copy assets to the temp directory fine because they don't need to execute, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `%TMP%` in a terminal/console window before running the installer, there is no need to edit the registry.

In NSIS v3+ you can use UnsafeStrCpy:

```
Function .onInit
UnsafeStrCpy $Temp "c:\foo\bar"
CreateDirectory "$Temp"
FunctionEnd
```

The real problem is the security "solution", why would preventing execution from %Temp% but not from other directories really provide any protection after the bad guys find out about this restriction?

Answer (score 0):

If the installer is started with the special **_?=$InstDir** parameter then it is not copied to %Temp%.

Try this (look for more info in documentation) maybe it is safer than overriding $Temp folder and so on.