# Building Electron App in Windows with Different Temporary Folder

Tags: windows, installation, electron

Is there a way to configure the path of temporary folders that get created when I run the installer of an application based on Electron? Instead of `~\AppData\Local\Temp`, I'd like to use a different folder, e.g., `c:\Temp`. The screenshot below shows a temporary folder that gets created as the application installer is running. At the end, all files are deleted but nsProcess.dll. I'd like this folder (and potential others) to be created in a different location.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Temp` in the installer comes from `%Temp%` set by the system (usually from the registry) and there is generally no need to change it.

[If you must](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29397991/3501), you can do this:

```
Function .onInit
UnsafeStrCpy $Temp "c:\foo\bar"
CreateDirectory "$Temp"
UnsafeStrCpy $PluginsDir $Temp
Initpluginsdir
FunctionEnd
```

However, $PluginsDir is normally deleted when the installer quits and if not it usually means something is holding a lock on a file.

In your case, try:

```
Section "my last section"
...
${nsProcess::Unload}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: NOTE: You tagged this as electron and not NSIS but I don't know anything about electron-builder and I answered just generically for how you would do it in NSIS.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give that a try and report back. Where would the `Function .onInit` code go?

Comment: Anywhere in the .nsi that is not inside another Section nor Function.

Comment: Found it. :) Is there a macro to detect the operating system (Windows vs. Mac vs. Linux)? I don't need to know the Windows version, just if it's Windows or not.

Comment: Do you mean in the NSIS compiler/your .nsi? The generated NSIS installer only runs on Windows. Either way, that sounds like it is off-topic here.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed that if I modify installer.nsi as you suggested, the temporary directory changed to what I specified. I'd like to: 1. Check the operating system (I only want to do this if it's on Windows), 2. Check if the new `$Temp` folder exists, 3. Delete it and recreate it.

Comment: 1) I don't understand, your .exe will only run on Windows. 2&3) Fix the cause, don't change $Temp. Did you try the unload thing from my answer?

Comment: I'll try it later, but first I'd like to make sure no folders are created under `~\AppData\Local\Temp` when running the installer. After applying your suggestion, all of those DLLs shown in the attached image get created under `c:\Temp`, but it still creates a folder under `~\AppData\Local\Temp` with System.dll and StdUtils.dll. The only way to completely avoid that is to manually set `TEMP` and `TMP` in CMD and then run the installer from it. What else should I do in addition to `UnsafeStrCpy $Temp "c:\Temp"` etc.?

Comment: It should work as is. Do you have anything else in your .onInit?

Comment: I edited my question with more information. Do you think another command is creating the temporary folder where I don't want it to? Maybe I should change the order of some commands?

Comment: You need to put the UnsafeStrCpy calls first in .onInit, not after your other code!

Comment: Duh! :) Yes, that worked. Thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: One more related question, if I may. I'd like the final target/executable to be in a different location than `~\AppData\Local\Programs`. I added `UnsafeStrCpy $INSTDIR "c:\Temp"` to the top of `.onInit`, but that didn't help. What am I missing?

Comment: That is a bit hard to answer without seeing your script. Look at where you set $InstDir and calls to SetOutPath.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/1961#issuecomment-324743484) did it. But I'm wondering if there's a way to do it without invoking HKEY.

Comment: Maybe not. There's a macro called `setInstallModePerUser` that first does `ReadRegStr $perUserInstallationFolder HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation` and if that returns an empty string, it uses the user's AppData path (`StrCpy $0 "$LocalAppData\Programs"`) which gets set when there's a call to `SetShellVarContext current`. At least that's my understanding.

Comment: That sounds about right and is the correct location for per-user installations.